# Intellij idea.exe.vmptions heap space 1g causes errors

Tags: intellij-idea

when I update idea.exe.vmoptions to be as follows:

`-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=300m
-ea`

I get an error:

"The JVM could not be started. The main method may have thrown and exception".

Yet when I start with idea.bat, which essentially parses the same file, it works fine.

I'm not sure if the above error logs somewhere so I've not had much success in chasing this down, and I've not spent long on it as idea.bat worked around it. Just wondering if anyone knows why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've covered this problem in the [IntelliJ IDEA FAQ article](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1185).

Comment: apologies - should have checked the FAQ more thoroughly! Many thanks.